# sampling of a random variable

Tags: sampling

I came up with the following question when I read a [paper](http://people.hss.caltech.edu/~mshum/gradio/papers/Pakes1986.pdf) in Economics:

> Let $Z:\Omega\to\Bbb{R}$ be a random variable with density 
>   $$
> f(z)=\begin{cases}
> \frac{1}{\sigma}\exp\left({-\frac{z+\mu}{\sigma}}\right),&\quad z+\mu\geq 0\\
> 0,&\quad\text{ otherwise}.
> \end{cases}
> $$
>   where $\mu$ and $\sigma$ are constants. Give $\theta\in(0,1)$, define a random variable $R:\Omega\to\Bbb{R}$ such that
>   $$
> P(R=0)=\theta,\quad P(R=Z)=1-\theta.
> $$

Here are my questions:

- [Added:] How can I generate a numerical sample of $R$, using the [inverse transform sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling)?
- Is there any other way than the [inverse transform sampling] to generate a sample?

Comment: $R$ is a _mixed_ random variable that has a continuous distribution on $(-\mu, \infty)$ and an atom at $0$. Thus, the CDF has a jump discontinuity at $0$ that you would need to take into account in getting a sample of $R$ from R.

Comment: @Dilip Alternatively, you can represent $R=ZU$ where $U$ is an independent Bernoulli variable with probability $1-\theta$ of being $1$ and probability $\theta$ of being $0$.

Comment: @whuber If I had to devise a method, then (taking $\mu=0$ and $\sigma=1$ for simplicity) I would do something like `Generate` $Z \sim U(0,1)$. `if` $(1-\theta) < Z < 1$, `return` $0$, `else return` $-\ln \frac{Z}{1-\theta}$ which requires only one call to a random number generator.  For other values of $\mu$ and $\sigma$, all that is needed is to modify the $-\ln \frac{Z}{1-\theta}$ appropriately. Of course, this _does_ use inverse transform sampling and so is not an answer to the_question_ asked here: "Is there any _other_ way than inverse transform sampling?"

Comment: @Dilip Very good! If you want to avoid inverse transform sampling, then you might recognize an exponential distribution as a (recentered, rescaled) $\chi^2_2$ distribution, which is easily sampled by summing the squares of two independent standard Normal variates. As you know, there are many ways to generate those without inverse transformations. Or, you could interpret the question specifically as wishing to avoid use of the inverse transform of $R$, which you have already accomplished.

Comment: @DilipSarwate and whuber,  thank you very much for your comment. I edited my question accordingly so that one can see the useful comments as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Discussion in comments above converted into an answer.

You can generate a sample of $R$ using the following method which *uses*
inverse transform sampling but *not* the inverse transform of $R$ which
has a *mixed* distribution that would need some extra steps in
handling via *direct* inverse transform sampling.

Notice that $Z$ is an *exponential* random variable with mean $\sigma$
that has been displaced to the left by $\mu$, that is,
$\displaystyle \frac{Z+\mu}{\sigma}$ is an exponential random
variable with mean $1$. So, we can use the following method to
generate a sample of $R$.

- Generate $Y \sim U(0,1)$.
- If $1-\theta < Y < 1$, set $R = 0$, else set 
  $\displaystyle R = -\sigma \ln\left(\frac{Y}{1-\theta}\right) - \mu$.

If $Y$ is known to have value in 
$(0, 1-\theta)$, the *conditional* distribution
of $\frac{Y}{1-\theta}$  is uniform on $(0,1)$ and so
$-\ln \left(\frac{Y}{1-\theta}\right)$ is an exponential
random variable with mean $1$. This is readily converted
to an exponential random variable with mean $\sigma$ and then
displaced by $\mu$ to the left.